# Finding number(s) that is(are) repeated consecutively most often

Tags: arrays, matlab

Given this array for example:
a = [1 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 4 4 4 5 1]

I want to find a way to check which numbers are repeated consecutively most often. In this example, the output should be [2 4] since both 2 and 4 are repeated three times consecutively.
Another example:
a = [1 1 2 3 1 1 5]

This should return [1 1] because there are separate instances of 1 being repeated twice.

This is my simple code. I know there is a better way to do this:

```
function val=longrun(a)

b = a(:)';
b = [b, max(b)+1];
val = [];
sum = 1;
max_occ = 0;
for i = 1:max(size(b))
    q = b(i);
    for j = i:size(b,2)
        if (q == b(j))
            sum = sum + 1;
        else
            if (sum > max_occ)
                max_occ = sum;
                val = [];
                val = [val, q];
            elseif (max_occ == sum)
                val = [val, q];
            end
            sum = 1;
            break;
        end
    end
end
if (size(a,2) == 1)
    val = val'
end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the code in my question. Please check it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a couple of *O(n)* passes through the array rather than an *O(n^2)* double loop. The first pass should create a new array containing the number of consecutive duplicates to that point in the array `b`.

Comment: This is exactly why I am asking this question. I know there is a simpler way but I cannot seem to find the required logic.

Comment: If you tag someone when you reply to them like @beaker, they'll be notified that you've responded. (I didn't have to tag you because the author of the post is always notified of new comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
%Dummy data
a = [1 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 4 4 4 5 5]

%Preallocation 
x = ones(1,numel(a));

%Loop 
for ii = 2:numel(a)
    if a(ii-1) == a(ii)
        x(ii) = x(ii-1)+1;
    end
end

%Get the result
a(find(x==max(x)))
```

With a simple for loop.

The goal here is to increase the value of `x` if the previous value in the vector `a` is identical.

Or you could also vectorized the process:

```
x = a(find(a-circshift(a,1,2)==0)); %compare a with a + a shift of 1 and get only the repeated element.
u = unique(x);                      %get the unique value of x
h = histc(x,u);                     
res = u(h==max(h))                  %get the result
```

Comment: I like this solution (the first one) because of its simplicity. I am still in the process of learning MATLAB so I am not really knowledgeable with many of the functions.

Comment: Yeah indeed the first solution is way more easier to understand. Happy learning!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized way:

```
a = [1 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 4 4 4 5 1]; % input data
t = cumsum([true logical(diff(a))]); % assign a label to each run of equal values
[~, n, z] = mode(t); % maximum run length and corresponding labels
result = a(ismember(t,z{1})); % build result with repeated values
result = result(1:n:end); % remove repetitions
```

Comment: This works quite well, thank you for your time. I am relatively new to MATLAB so this is a chance for me to learn new functions.